# Web API call works but gives exception The view 'xxx' or its master was not found or no view engine supports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Strange one here, code calls the method, and the method `grabacat` is executed on the server (I debug it and step through right to the end). The code returns to the client, but the response it received was 500 Internal Server Error with the above message. So it's saying it couldn't find the web API method that it just called successfully.

```
using (var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("cats/grabacat", mycatprefs))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // 500 cats/grabacat not found
```

Controller code:

```
[Route("~/api/cats/grabacat")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task GrabACat()
{
}
```

After debugging, if I change it to `public async Task<SomeObject> GrabACat()` then it works OK. This lets me return an object back to the client. However I don't *want* to return anything back; I want it to be equivelent to calling a `void` method. It will examine the status code to determine if it was successful.

I have got it working by changing GrabACat to Task and returning `new object();` but I am not sure why this is required. It seems crude to return an empty object just to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy your grabacat action here? It seems like you are returning a view from there

Comment: show the controller code.

Comment: Does the controller in your inherit from `ApiController` and what is the return type? I think we need to see the controller code.

Comment: From which view are you calling? What's the controller method (the one which throws the exception)? What are you trying to post back?

Comment: I am posting some data, I don't want to return anything as the method is void and doesn't return anything, it should just be 200 OK. The problem is not around the URL it is around returning an object vs. void

Comment: Your comment says you get a 500 error, which does **not** mean "Not Found" (that's a 404), but it means a server error occurred. Do some logging and debugging, probably you have a serialization error. What is the actual response message of the request? Why is your action method an `async Task`?

Comment: There is no error in the server code. The error is due to me calling a method that has no return type. It runs and completes but the client has an error, presumably because there is no return object coming back. But I don't *want* any return data. I just want to call a web API method and have it return 200 OK, not return some kind of .NET complex type.

Comment: _"There is no error in the server code"_ - there is, just not directly in your code. You claim you get a 500 error from your API call, WebAPI still does some processing after your code returns. You need to find that error. What does the API method return? `return Ok();`? What is the response message of the request? What does `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` show you? You're nearing your 500th question, you should know to include more detail in your question by now. :-) This is not enough information for anyone to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I have to agree with everything @CodeCaster says here. Also, do you really need it to be async?

Comment: So there's no error in the server code, and you say there there is, but not in the code... *facepalm*. As stated in my question, the `response` object is 500 and the error is the one in the question title. You came here assuming I'd done some beginner error in my server code, you edited your comment when you realised it was something more, and you're asking things that are already in the question. You should be more respectful and possibly answer questions that don't involve your wild speculation. The method needs to be async yes, because it is long-running.

Comment: Wow, that attitude. Let me recap: your call to WebAPI returns you an error, right? So there is an error in your code. The fact that you can step through your API method, does not mean that that code is good. WebAPI does some processing after running your code, and if your code is faulty, it is perfectly possible to get errors after successfully stepping though your code. You're using `async` wrong and that's the source of your error. You shouldn't start long-running tasks from ASP.NET, and `async` won't help. If WebAPI returns a 500 error with something about views, your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The WebAPI method has a Route attribute like this:

```
[Route("~/api/cats/grabacat")]
```

Which means the URL is wrong in the POST request - you are missing the `/api` prefix:

```
using (var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("api/cats/grabacat", mycatprefs))
    //snip
```

Comment: Possibly, but it's impossible to call that method with the URL shown here.

Comment: The method call works fine. It is also fixed by returning an object of some sort. So I'm wondering why an object must be returned.

Comment: @SLC Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. How can you return an object when it's an async Task call?

Comment: The broken code is `async Task`. If I change the return type to `async Task<someObject>` then it works. But I don't want to return `someObject`, I don't want to return anything.

Comment: Are you `await`ing anything in the API method?